# how to check ajax code is executed or not?

Tags: javascript, ajax

How to Get to Know whether the file called in the ajax code is been executed or not?

```
function get_data(radioAns) 
{
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
        {
            document.getElementById("dataExchange").innerHTML =this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET","example.php?radioAns="+radioAns, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Here is my ajax code..
i want to know how to check whether the example.php file is called or not.

Comment: Right click on DOM and select `Inspect Element` or (CTRL + SHIFT + i). From there go to `Network` Tab, then make the call and you will see its details over there.

Comment: I need that error in my code.. So that i can throe a exception if it is'nt executed succesfully.

Comment: That depends on your backend code.
If you see the `preview` or `response` tab you will be able to see what backend is returning. 
Can you paste the response here so that I can guide you exactly.

Comment: It return some text in the response that is been included into a div named dataexchange

Comment: Then my friend you are not using JSON encoding on the backend. 
You need to return key value pairs so that you can apply checks on front end. An example of a valid json response may be `"{"status":false,"message":"Ajax call failed"}"`

Comment: my returns it as a object but when i try to get it printed it only gives some text data.

Comment: Can you paste the response here?

Comment: my doubt was not with response. i was asking that how to know if the file is not even called. like the if the file not found or something like that.

Comment: Then you can use another condition `this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 404` as 404 is the for file not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate your checks for `readyState` and `status`.

A `readyState` of `4` (or `XMLHttpRequest.DONE` if you like constants) indicates the request has completed (either successfully or in error).

A status of `[200, 300)` is generally considered successful. `[300, 400)` usually indicates some kind of content-less response (like a redirect). Anything equal to or greater than `400` is an error.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

With all that in mind, consider something like

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
      // success
    }
    if (this.status >= 400) {
      // error
    }
  }
  // else, the request has not completed *yet*
}
```